# Picasso Not Loading image from url

Tags: android, picasso

So I am trying to simply load an image from a url(its valid) to an imageView using Picasso. I have added the Picasso libary via gradle and I have added both:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to my code as many other users have pointed out.
  I don't have any errors and it simply doesn't do anything even after 10+ seconds.
Here is my Java method:

```
ImageView image;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(image);
}
```

and my activity XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.benhouse.testproj.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work?
I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake somewhere.

Comment: Please try glide library...some times i have faced issue like this using picasso but it resolved with glide.https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Kindly mentioned  the device or API Level

Comment: Check your XML.I think the mistake is in an XML file. If you are using constraint layout than why you use relative layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent Relative Layout height and width is 0dp that's why childLayout(ImageView) unable to show image .So, you need to set Relative layout height and width wrap_content or match_parent. like that:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.benhouse.testproj.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Using `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in Application Tag of your Manifest file!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try 2 things here.

1.Provide placeholder for image to make sure Picasso is working fine.

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.image_name)
```

2.Write use-permission twice in manifest. [I know this may sound crazy but there was some version of grade/studio which had this bug]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: why are you adding the permission twice?? Adding Singley can do work.I

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use constraint layout and center the image you'll need to use below constraints to your relative layout..

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Comment: Constraint layout was used as parent so this its actually covering the whole parent.